# Windows Forms: Button with menu

Tags: .net, winforms-interop

Is it possible to implement a button, which opens a menu on it? I need something like **button style combobox** or a **dropdown button**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absent a mock-up image or a little better explanation, I'm not sure if I completely understand what the element that you're trying to create looks like and how it should work. Mostly, I just don't understand what a "button style combobox" is. That being said...

**I suggest taking a careful look at wyDay's [SplitButton](http://wyday.com/splitbutton/) control.** It's free and open source, and allows you to add a context menu to your button that drops down whenever the button is clicked. 
Plus, I feel like the other advantage to using something like this is that it replicates a common UI element. Lots of Microsoft's own software, and plenty of that available from other developers as well, uses a similarly-styled control. Things like this make it likely that your users will immediately grasp how to use it.

[image: SplitButton demonstration]

Because I'm obsessively picky, I've implemented my own custom drop-down button control using this as a model, but it should work fine for 99% of applications right out of the box. So in the event that you're looking for something extra, it's trivial to add it onto the existing base control.

Answer (score 3):

The standard .NET ToolStripSplitButton control works like this.  You have to put it on a ToolStrip.  You could undock the strip and set its GripStyle to Hidden to make it resemble a regular button.